# Why tests fail when run in eclipse after creating through selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium-ide, junit

I have created many tests using Selenium IDE and exported into java files in order to run in eclipse. All tests work properly in Selenium IDE but when I run in eclipse(java file) it creates following exception. But I have added wait commands in appropriate places and also additional pause commands too. Still get these error messages

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2]/select")).click();
{
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/select")));
}
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/select")).sendKeys("Act/Act");
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]/div[1]/div/div[2]/select")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]")).sendKeys("Overnight");
{
  WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]/select"));
  dropdown.findElement(By.cssSelector("*:nth-child(1)")).click();
}
```

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
>     (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
>
> Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d24..., userDataDir: C:\Users\AppData\Loc...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:65130}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 74.0.3729.169, webStorageEnabled: true}
>   Session ID: f06036421f7999c863f76b8f1143ddcf
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:285)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:106)
>       at RepoDeals.RepoTest.publishREPOValidFirmQuoteUsingPredefinedTenorAndPredefinedTime(RepoTest.java:86)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

I think execution speed is the problem in here. How can I fix this? Is there any other reasons?

Comment: Which step is it showing the `ElementNotInteractableException` on? While it seems weird that it works in Selenium IDE, maybe focusing on fixing that will shed some light.

Comment: It creates the error in line "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]")).sendKeys("Overnight");"

Answer (score 0):

Finally it turned out to be a xpath problem. I changed xpath of

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]")).sendKeys("Overnight");
```

to

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[5]/div[3]/div[1]")).sendKeys("Overnight");
```

now it works